# Eigenstates for a modified quantum harmonic oscillator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

Suppose that the potential of the oscillator is given by $V(x)=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 x^2+\lambda x$. How would you go about solving for the eigenstates. My work thus far is this.

I wrote the time independent Schrodinger equation,

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}+\left(\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 x^2+\lambda x\right)\psi=E\psi\rightarrow\left(\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 x^2+\lambda x\right)\psi=E\psi.$$

The Hamiltonian is then,

$$\hat{H}=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 x^2+\lambda x.$$

I tried rewriting the expression in terms of the ladder operators, and got the following.

$$\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{2}\hbar\omega(a_++a_-)+\lambda\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}(a_++a_-).$$

I honestly have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: No. All we really covered so far in class has been change of basis, Dirac notation. Basically everything in the first chapter of Shankar.

Comment: Why don't you represent the original Hamiltonian (with the second order position derivatives) in terms of the raising and lowering operators?

Comment: Ok, you can make a change of variables for V (x) and complete the square. You should then find a solution in terms of the standard SHO solutions.

Comment: It is not necessary to pass to raising and lowering operators. $H= H_1 -\frac{1}{2} (\lambda/\sqrt{m}\omega)^2\:I$, where $H_1 = UH_0U^{-1}$ is the standard Hamiltonian of the harmonic oscillator with $x$ replaced for $x+  (\lambda/\sqrt{m}\omega)2\:I$. $U$ is an unitary operator generating that translation. Since unitary transformations preserve the spectrum $\sigma(H)= \{\hbar \omega(n+1/2) -\frac{1}{2} (\lambda/\sqrt{m}\omega)^2\:|\: n =0,1,2,\ldots, \}$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$
\frac{1}{2} m \omega^2 x^2 + \lambda x = \frac{1}{2} m \omega^2 \left( x + \frac{\lambda}{m\omega^2} \right)^2  -  \frac{\lambda^2}{2 m\omega^2} 
$$
Now, if I define the quantities
\begin{align}
y &= x + \frac{\lambda}{m\omega^2} ~, \\
\Psi(y) &= \psi \left( y - \frac{\lambda}{m\omega^2} \right) ~, \\
{\cal E} &= E +  \frac{\lambda^2}{2 m\omega^2} ~. 
\end{align}
Then, the differential equation that $\Psi(y)$ satisfies is
$$
- \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \Psi''(y) + \frac{1}{2} m \omega^2 y^2 \Psi(y) = {\cal E} \Psi(y)
$$

I leave it to you to proceed from here.